# C++11: How to initialize array of pointers of some class with nullptr?

Tags: c++, c++11, nullptr

I am new to C++. I have class named `MyDate`. In addition I have a class named `Calendar` which has a member type of array of pointers to `MyDate` objects. How should I declare and initialize members of the array to `nullptr` in the constructor of `Calendar`?

Comment: See if you can avoid having this array of pointers in the first place

Answer (score 4):

Smart pointers default-initialize to `nullptr`:

```
class Calendar
{
    std::array<std::unique_ptr<Date>, 42> m_dates;
};
```

Otherwise, `std::array` is an aggregate, so an empty braced init list will zero-initialize all scalar fields:

```
class Calendar
{
    std::array<Date *, 42> m_dates {};
};
```

Comment: Indeed, you seem to be correct according to Clang and GCC. However, to work around a `-Wmissing-field-initializers` warning it were perhaps better to use `std::array<Date *, 42> m_dates {{nullptr}};`

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I'd probably do it like this:

```cxx
class Calendar {

/* Methods: */

    Calendar() noexcept
    { for (auto & ptr: m_dates) ptr = nullptr; }

/* Fields: */

    /* Array of 42 unique pointers to MyDate objects: */
    std::array<MyDate *, 42> m_dates;

};
```

PS: You might want to consider using smart pointers like `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr` instead of raw pointers. Then you wouldn't need to explicitly initialize these in the `Calendar` constructor at all:

```
class Calendar {

/* Fields: */

    /* Array of 42 pointers to MyDate objects: */
    std::array<std::unique_ptr<MyDate>, 42> m_dates;

};
```

**EDIT:** Without C++11 features, I'd do this:

```
class Calendar {

/* Methods: */

    Calendar()
    { for (std::size_t i = 0u; i < 42u; ++i) m_dates[i] = NULL; }

/* Fields: */

    /* Array of 42 unique pointers to MyDate objects: */
    MyDate * m_dates[42];

};
```

Comment: `std::array<MyDate *, 42> m_dates {};` is much simpler

Comment: @jotik- should I include some special library for the nullptr?

Comment: @saritrotshild No, its a C++11 feature. But you need `#include <array>` for `std::array` and `#include <memory>` for `std::unique_ptr`/`std::shared_ptr`.

Comment: @jotik- I get 2 errors.error:1. #error This file requires compiler and library support for the ISO C++ 2011 standard. This support is currently experimental, and must be enabled with the -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 compiler options.  2.error:'array' in namespace 'std' does not name a type.

Comment: Seems that you have an old compiler which does not fully support C++11. Since `nullptr`, `std::array`, and `std::unique_ptr`/`std::shared_ptr` are C++11 features, you must use a compiler supporting C++11. If you want to use C++03 or earlier, you should not have used `nullptr` in the original question, but `NULL`. In this case the question must be re-tagged etc. I added to my answer an example for earlier versions of C++.

Comment: If you are afraid of `std::array<MyDate *, 42> m_dates {};` you can use `m_dates.fill(nullptr)` which is simpler than an explicit iteration.