# Will the compiler generated default constructor initialize the pointers in std::array to nullptr?

Tags: c++, arrays, initialization, std

Is it correct that given the code below, the compiler should generate `Node()` which should call `std::array<Node *, 100>()` which should initialize all 100 pointers to nullptr.

Side note: I know that I can make that happen if I use `std::array<Node *, 100> children {};`, but I am not trying to get my code to work (it already does), I am trying to make sure that it's not working by accident.

```
struct Node
{
    int value;
    std::array<Node *, 100> children;
}
```

Update:

Here pointers are garbage:

```
struct Node
{
    int value;
    std::array<Node *, 100> children;
}

struct Node
{
    Node() : children() {}
    int value;
    std::array<Node *, 100> children;
}
```

Here pointers are nullptr:

```
struct Node
{
    int value;
    std::array<Node *, 100> children {};
}

struct Node
{
    Node() : children{} {}
    int value;
    std::array<Node *, 100> children;
}
```

Please, correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: What you want is to use `shared_ptr<Node *>` instead of bare pointers. Way less surprises in the end as long as you use them everywhere (consistently).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To quote [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) on the constructor of `std::array`:

> initializes the array following the rules of aggregate initialization
>   (note that default initialization may result in indeterminate values
>   for non-class T)

By declaring your variable like `std::array<Node *, 100> children;` you invoke the default constructor. And, according to the rules of initialization, PODs (`int`, `char`, `double`, pointers, ...) are not default initialized. So no, your array will not be initialized with `nullptr` if you don't use aggregate initialization.

### Aggregate initialization

```
std::array<Node *, 100> children;
```

invokes the default constructor, but no aggregate initializer is given so aggregate initialization won't happen. However

```
std::array<Node *, 100> children{}
std::array<Node *, 100> children = {};
```

not only invokes the default constructor, but also performs an aggregate initialization. In this case, the aggregate `{}` is just empty. And, following the rules of aggregate initialization, if there are less initializers than data members, every uninitialized member will be default initialized. So

```
Node x;
std::array<Node *, 100> children = {&x};
```

for example, will initialize the first array element with the pointer to `x` and every successive element will be default initialized to `nullptr`.

Comment: I would add clarification: No, the array will not be initialised with nullptr *if `Node` is default initialised*.

Comment: Some of the terminology is lost on me...

`std::array<Node *, 100> children {};`

will initialize all 100 pointers to nullptr according to this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35849693/c11-how-to-initialize-array-of-pointers-of-some-class-with-nullptr

Does that mean that

`Node() : children() {}`

doesn't do that, but

`Node() : children{} {}` would?

Comment: Amazing, it's very clean now. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18295302/default-initialization-of-stdarray), default initialization of a `std::array` of pointers will **not** initialize the pointers it contains, and their values will be indeterminate.

```
std::array<Node *, 100> children; // pointers are uninitialized
```

You can however use *value* initialization to initialize all the contained pointers to `nullptr`. On a `std::array`, this has the effect of value initializing each value in the array, which in turn zero-initializes every pointer.

```
std::array<Node *, 100> children {}; // pointers are all null
```

In a member initializer list, you can also do this as follows:

```
Node::Node() : children{/* value init array */} {/* empty c'tor body */}
```

Answer (score 0):

Until a pointer is assigned a value, it points to a "garbage" address by default. The compiler does not assign them a default value of `nullptr`. In fact, it does not assign any "default" value to pointers.
**Edit:**
From the cppreference [documentation for std::array](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array):

> note that default initialization may result in indeterminate values for non-class T

So if you use the default constructor, you need to assign each element a value of `nullptr` yourself.